# Call ActionResult when a checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call an ActionResult when a checkbox is checked, but i do not know why it's not working 
Here is my code below .

--Checkbox

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" id=@item.EmployeeId  />
</td>
```

--Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e)
    {

        if (e.target.checked)
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var url = "Employee/ShowPopUpDelete?id=" + id;
            $("#ModalBody").load(url,function()
            {
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            })
        }


   });
</script>
```

--Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowPopUpDelete(int id)
    {
        Employee temp = new Employee();
        temp = EM.FindById(id);

        ViewBag.Msg = "Are you sure?";


        return PartialView("Delete",temp);
    }
```

The FindById returns the Employee object that has the given Id. When i Debug it just ignores my ShowPopUpDelete ActionResult . I would appreciate to know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: `EM.FindById(id);` what is the `EM` in the code?

Comment: EmployeeModule instance - EmployeeModule EM = new EmployeeModule();

Comment: "When i Debug it just ignores my ShowPopUpDelete ActionResult ", can you explain a little more what you mean by this? i mean full scenario

Comment: You aren't ever reading the response on the client side.

Comment: I mean that it doesnt call the Action for some reason . @MahabubulHasan

Comment: @Drey what's your jquery version? instead of your `$("#ModalBody").load` can you try `.get(url, data, success)` ??

Comment: `$.get("Employee/ShowPopUpDelete?id=" + id, function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });`

Comment: @MahabubulHasan It doesn't do anything . I am using this reference for jquery <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Checkbox

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1234" />
</td>
```

Script

```
$("#1234").change(function()
{

    if (this.checked)
    {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

        var url = "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")" + "?id=" + id;
        $("#modelbody").load(url,function()
        {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked when i changed my url definition to yours . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it this way?

`<input type="checkbox" onchange="handleModal(event)">`

Then

```
function handleModal(e) {
     if (e.target.checked)
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var url = "Employee/ShowPopUpDelete?id=" + id;
        $("#ModalBody").load(url,function()
        {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It keeps ignoring ShowPopUpDelete .Also ,on the checkbox, don't i have to add id=@item.EmployeeId to pass the id ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that, you should add Id. My bad.

Comment: ok, try passing the url as a data like so:

 `<input type="checkbox" id=@item.EmployeeId onchange="handleModal(event)" data-url="@Url.Action("Employee", "ShowPopUpDelete")"/>`

then you can retrieve the url like so: 
var id = $(this).attr('data-url');

Comment: Would you mind to type the full jquery code like that?

Answer (score 0):

You may miss ready function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var url = "Employee/ShowPopUpDelete?id=" + id;
                $("#ModalBody").load(url, function () {
                    $("#myModal").modal("show");
                })
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

**For more Refer below Link**

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php